# How do I load multiple scripts without them colliding?

Tags: jquery, performance, src

I'm working on a site that needs to load multiple scripts. However, every now and then, one or two of them won't load.

Is there a better way to load scripts to a page than what I have below? ( see http://www.pushpinevents.com/alarm )

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Alarm of America</title>


<script  type="text/javascript" src="java/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="java/jkmegamenu.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    jkmegamenu.definemenu("megaanchor0", "megamenu0", "mouseover");
    jkmegamenu.definemenu("megaanchor2", "megamenu2", "mouseover");
    jkmegamenu.definemenu("megaanchor3", "megamenu3", "mouseover");
    jkmegamenu.definemenu("megaanchor4", "megamenu4", "mouseover");
</script>




<script  type="text/javascript" src="java/slides.js"></script>


<script  type="text/javascript" src="curvycorners.src.js"></script>





<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mainbanner').ready(function() {
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 842,
        height: 325,
    play: {
      active: false,
        // [boolean] Generate the play and stop buttons.
        // You cannot use your own buttons. Sorry.
      effect: "fade",
        // [string] Can be either "slide" or "fade".
      interval: 2000,
        // [number] Time spent on each slide in milliseconds.
      auto: true,
        // [boolean] Start playing the slideshow on load.

      pauseOnHover: true,
        // [boolean] pause a playing slideshow on hover
      restartDelay: 2500,
        // [number] restart delay on inactive slideshow

    },

    navigation: false



      });
    });
  </script>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

Comment: When you say they don't load, what do you mean? Are you getting any errors? Is it possible you are trying to call functions before they are included (such as `jkmegamenu.definemenu`). Also, your use of the jquery onready handler should probably use the `document` selector, rather than `#mainbanner`: `$(document).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
});`. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/). It is a file and module loader that provides structure and certainty to loading scripts.

Comment: Taking a look... basically, sometimes the image slider won't load, and the image space will be blank. Sometimes the megamenu won't load and the menues render in the page off to the side. etc...